# Is it necessary to mix old corpus and new corpus in updating word2vec model?

Tags: gensim, word2vec

I found it is not explicit in usage

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
sentences = [["cat", "say", "meow"], ["dog", "say", "woof"]]

model = Word2Vec(min_count=1)
model.build_vocab(sentences)  # prepare the model vocabulary
model.train(sentences, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.iter)  # train word vectors
(1, 30)
```

the sentences whether should contain the old corpus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't show any incremental updating of an old model with new examples.

However, it's never guaranteed that incremental updating (as with `build_vocab(new_sentences, update=True)` and then `train(new_sentences, ...)`) necessarily improves the model overall.

The underlying algorithm gets its strength from a large dataset, of subtly-varied usage examples, being trained together in an interleaved fashion. The contrasting examples "pull" the model in various ways, sometimes reinforcing each other and sometimes cancelling out, resulting in final word-vector arrangements that are useful for other purposes.

Let's say you then do an incremental update with texts that are not the same as the original training data. (And after all, they must be meaningfully different, or else you wouldn't bother with more training.) During that new training, only the words affected by the new (possibly-smaller) dataset are changing. And they're changing just to be better at the new text examples. Any words (or senses-of-words) that only appeared in earlier data aren't being updated... and so the new training unavoidably pulls current words out of the balanced relationship with older words that existed after joint training.

In the extreme in some neural-network models, such new-data training can lead to "[catastrophic interference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_interference)", making the network much worse at things it once knew.

It might still work out ok, if there's a good overlap of vocabulary, or the right level of re-training and balance of learning-rates is chosen... but there are no hard-and-fast rules for picking the parameters/processes that make sure such 'tuning' works. You have to monitor the quality and optimize it yourself.

The safest, most robust course, when significant new data arrives, is to re-train the model from scratch using all available data – discarding the old model (because coordinates int he new model may not necessarily be comparable with older coordinates). It may be the case that starting this new model with vectors/weights from the old model may help it reach quality/stability sooner than starting from scratch – but still wouldn't guarantee coordinate-compatibility, or necessarily make it safe to leave out any older data.

Comment: So,only updating model with new data is risk.The best way to update model is: load model, build vocab with old+new data,then train it?

Comment: The `build_vocab(..., update=True)` call may not need the old data, since it keeps prior words. (But, if there's a word that's below `min_count` occurrences in the old data, and then below it in the new data, but would be frequent-enough if combined, you might want to combine it all.) Then doing `train()` with all data will help guard against imbalance between old/new examples. But you'll still want to monitor quality closely, and if doing all that, may just want to re-train from scratch (or at least compare that as an option).